# A method that receives a list<strings> and a int n, returns the word that repeats n times in the list

Tags: c#, .net

I tried to do a `foreach` but I don't know how to save the iteration for the words and compare with the integer

```cs
var words = new List<String> {"Mike", "Mia" ,"Mike", "Frank" ,"Mike", "Lisa", "Joss", "Frank" };
int number = 3;

String find(List<String> lst, int n) 
{
  //what goes here?
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
var result = lst.GroupBy(x=> x).Where(x=> x.Count() == n).Select(x=> x.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions

Answer (score 1):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/TWaSGg

I modified it a bit to return all strings that were repeated 'n' times though

```
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var words = new List<String> {"Mike", "Mia" ,"Mike", "Frank" ,"Mike", "Lisa", "Joss", "Frank" };
        int number = 3;
        var result = find(words,number);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",result));
    }
    
    

private static IList<string> find(List<String> lst, int n) 
{
  
    return  lst.GroupBy(x=>x).Where(y=>y.Count()==n).Select(val=>val.Key).ToList();
    
}
}
```